# Access date calculation

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am pretty new to access SQL and trying to figure out what this date calculation means:

```
>Date() And <DateAdd("d",
                     -1,
                     DateAdd("m",
                              8,
                              DateAdd("d",
                                       -(Day(Date())-1),
                                       Date())
                            )
                     )
```

Any help interpreting would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the last expression:

```
DateAdd("d",-1,DateAdd("m",8,DateAdd("d",-(Day(Date())-1),Date())))
```

It's easier to read if you separate out the function arguments to their own line:

```
DateAdd(
    "d",
    -1,
    DateAdd(
        "m",
        8,
        DateAdd(
            "d",
            - ( Day( Date() ) - 1 ),
            Date()
        )
    )
)
```

- `DateAdd( "d", a, b )` Adds `a`-many days to `b`.
- `DateAdd( "m", a, b )` Adds `a`-many months to `b`.
- `( Day( Date() ) - 1 )` is today's day-of-month, minus 1 (`Date()` is `2017-02-07`, so the result is `6`.
- `DateAdd( "d", -6, Date() )` will subtract 6 days from today's date, so the result is `2017-02-01`.
- `DateAdd( "m", 8, (2017-02-01) )` will add 8 months to `2017-02-01`, so the result is `2017-10-01`.
- `DateAdd( "d", -1, (2017-10-01) )` will subtract 1 day from `2017-10-01`, so the result is `2017-09-30`.

So the expression your originally posted then becomes: `> Date() AND < (2017-09-30)`. This is not valid SQL because the comparison operators `<`, `>`, and `=` need two operands each. It's possible the author thinks they're used like the `BETWEEN` operator, but they're wrong.

Out of curiosity, I turned these `DateAdd` operations into a function and produced a plot of the function against the range of dates in 2017:

[image]

It looks like its a function to **get the date of the last-day of the month that is 8 months from the present**, so any `Date()` in January 2017 (`01-31`) results in `2017-08-31`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use *DateSerial*, at least easier and faster to comprehend:

```
>DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) + 8, 0)
```

Also, I guess it really should read `>=`, thus your criteria could read:

```
>Date() And <=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())+8,0)
```